# Discord.py: How to send a message without using async and await

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

How can I create a function (without async) that sends a message to a specific channel every time it (the function) gets executed somewhere in the code?

```py
def sendMsg():
    channel = client.getChannel(Channel id)
    message.channel.send("example message")
    #excecuting the function
    sendMsg()
```

Doesn't do anything

```py
async def on_message():
    await message.channel.send("example message")
```

Only this one works

So my question is if I can modify the code on the top make it work?

Comment: Please include a [mre]. It's impossible to send the message through discordpy without using asyncio. The closest you can get is making a class. You may want to read the documentation for asyncio.

Comment: The one that you said "works" **does not work**. The `await` is necessary.

Comment: @EricJin sorry, in my working code, I used await. Only forgot to write it in the example

Comment: You need `async def send_msg` and then you can use `await message.channel.send` in front of it. Also `message` isn't defined in there - did you mean to have it be a global or passed as argument?

Comment: >Also message isnt defined.   Well idk, but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send the message outside of an async context, you need to add the task into the event loop. Note that when you "call" a coroutine, you get the actual coroutine object. "Calling" it doesn't actually run the coroutine, you need to put it in the event loop for it to run.

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(<coro>)

# use it like this
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(ctx.send('test'))
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(message.channel.send("example message"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer is correct. Moreover, in order to get the loop event from discord.py, you can use `client.loop` to get discord.py's asyncio eventloop

that said, use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(def,loop)` to safely submit task to event_loop

```py
client = discord.Client()
async def send_message_to_specific_channel(message='abc',id=123):
  channel = client.get_channel(id)
  await channel.send(message)
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_message_to_specific_channel('abc',123),client.loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Async is really needed for synchronize the message

If your wanna make it as selfbot response message, do

```
# Import's here
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None, self_bot=True)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
       await message.channel.send(f"Hi @{message.author}")


bot.run('token ofc', bot=False)
```

Anyways this for selfbot if you wanna do it with bots, delete `self_bot=True` and `bot=False`