# Sending a DM to Discord user via API without on_event or a listener

Tags: python, rest, discord.py, webhooks

I have an app where I want to send DM messages to a Discord user (me or someone else) when something happens with my Python code (e.g new user signup on my website).
I don't need to listen to discord events and I don't need to keep the network communication open. Is there any way where I can just send the message (post method of api like we use normally) to discord server without listening to events?
So far, I have been able to do this to send to a channel using webhooks (see below). However, webhooks do not support DMs.

Code for webhook notifications in channel:

```
import requests
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter

webhook = Webhook.from_url("url-here", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
webhook.send("Hello World")
```

Comment: How do you know that a new user has signed up on your website? When it happens, you can just send the message. For example: `def website.on_user_sign_up():  <send the message>`. You probably would have to use `async-await` for this.

Comment: You may find [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672827/discord-py-how-to-send-a-message-without-using-async-and-await) helpful if your website handler can't use asyncio

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement this function as a callback to an event (webhook, API request, timer, etc.).
It will get the user by their `id`, optionally create `DMChannel` in case it doesn't exist and finally will send a message.

```
async def send_message(user_id, *args, **kwargs):
    user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
    if user.dm_channel is None:
        await user.create_dm()
    await user.dm_channel.send(*args, **kwargs)
```